# Saving related with User model objects

Tags: django

Why it's not working?

models.py:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

views.py:

```
def add_car(request, model):
    new_car = Car(owner=request.user.id, model=model)
    new_car.save()
```

The error:

```
ValueError at /add/
Cannot assign "7L": "Car.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

What is `7L`?
My user id is 7, when I write `print request.user.id` it's get me 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set to Car.user whole model, not only id.

```
new_car = Car(owner=request.user, model=model)
```

Comment: Or you could do `owner_id=request.user.id`, but it has to be id to id or object to object. You can't mix the two.